# Starting tasks returned by iterator methods in parallel

Tags: .net, vb.net, iterator, task-parallel-library

First look at this simple method:

```
Public Iterator Function GetLongRunningTasks(count As Long) As IEnumerable(Of Task)
    For i = 1 To count
        Yield Task.Delay(3000)
    Next
End Function
```

This method returns the specified amount of tasks, each one of which completes 3 seconds after it starts. Let's call it a simulation of a network API call on an extremely bad network connection (not that it matters).

My problem is that a simple iteration will start the tasks one at a time, so the 3000ms delay happens in between each iteration.

```
    For Each t In GetLongRunningTasks(50)
        Await t
    Next ' this takes ~150 seconds to complete (50x3000ms)
```

What I want to do is start all 50 tasks at once, then afterwards enter the foreach-loop. Preferably sticking to the example above, what is the proper way to do this?

**EDIT**

As suggested by Stephen, one solution is to iterate over `GetLongRunningTasks(50).ToList()`. Maybe it's just me but I don't think it's at all obvious why ToList is used when I read over the code.

I wonder if the following snippet is exactly the same?

```
    Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
    tasks.AddRange(GetLongRunningTasks(50))

    For Each t In tasks
        Await t
    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add some explanation to Stephen's answer: `GetLongRunningTasks()` returns a lazy iterator, which creates the `Task`s only when you iterate it. In your original code, each iteration creates a single `Task`, then waits for it to complete and only then another iteration starts, which starts another `Task`.

So, what you need it to first iterate over the whole collection to start all the `Task`s and wait for them to complete only when you have them all. Stephen's `ToList()` suggestion does exactly that, and your `AddRange()` would do the same.

If it still isn't clear to you, maybe one more way to do the same would help:

```
Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
For Each t in GetLongRunningTasks(50)
    tasks.Add(t)
Next

For Each t In tasks
    Await t
Next
```

Also, starting a large number of IO-bound `Task`s most likely isn't the most efficient option, running them with a limited degree of parallelism is. To do that, you could use `SemaphoreSlim`'s `WaitAsnyc()`, or use `ActionBlock` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set from TPL Dataflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `ToList` to create all the `Task`s. Then you can use `For Each` (or `Task.WhenAll` if you're just `Await`ing each one).